# How to locate hornet nest?

Tags: pest-control, insect

I live in semi-detached house and since some time I have encountered some wasps in my bedroom. It is placed on 1st floor (house has 2.5 floors) and I have encountered them only at night/late evening. I haven't seen nest yet, but I think that it has to be somewhere near (as it needs to see the light or something that attracts them only at night).

What is the easiest way to locate where the nest is that I can call service to remove it from my neighbourhood?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look around the perimeter of the house paying special attention to areas where the foundation meets the sill.

Those nasty wasps or hornets will find a way in a small crack or joint of the sill and build nests under the floor joists, especially if you have ceilings in the basement level.  They will also get into the attic under an eave or vent.  During the day you will see them coming in and out if you watch carefully.

I encountered a massive nest in a flip house I was working on. Every morning there were a couple of dozen wasps flying around the kitchen and living room.  They were actually entering the living space around heat pipes in the floor and around wall electrical outlets. (If they were in the attic, they could enter the house through light fixtures.)  I used a stethoscope on the floor to track down the nest, hands and knees crawling across the floor, listening for the "BUZZ". After I isolated the area they were in, it took me days and multiple attacks of grenade type bombs (6 or 8) into the cavity between the ceiling and first floor and several cans (10) of foaming wasp spray shot directly into the outdoor entry point to finally get rid of them.

The piles of dead wasps just outside the entry point got bigger every day.  Thousands of them.  I eventually sprayed insulation foam in the entry point, sealed it and that seemed to end the problem.  Not sure if your infestation can be DIY treated, but if you look around, I bet you can find where they are coming and going in your house.

Comment: The other way they come in is via the eves and the attic.  I noticed a nest in my soffit by watching the flow during the day.   It is best to attack after sunset, as they will mostly be in the nest, and sun provides their primary navigation clue. 

For some excitement, go to YouTube and search for the Hornet King and see some of his epic removals

Answer (score 0):

Wasps are most active midday when it is not cold.  You ought to be able to just follow them and see where they go.  Then, as shirlockhomes writes, off-the-shelf wasp killer to eradicate them.

Comment: Agreed, the wasps you are encountering in the evening are late returners heading back to the nest.

Comment: The problem is that I have never encountered them in the midday, either because it is to hot or because the nest isn't nearby enough. They only come to the light at the evening/night.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier:  Maybe try mid-morning; you are in the northern hemisphere, right?  If it is winter, then that does slow down wasps quite a bit.  Try standing where you have seen them and hold still for two minutes just watching.  If you see any, follow it.  Eventually you'll see three to five at a time.